# Issue with tracking accurate percentage on graph

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

My formula in excel has an issue with not calculating accurate result. I am trying to get the a percentage of how much has been completed in the action tracker.

I made this cool graph that involves two pie charts. One pie chart is the graph and the other is a dial. The dial has the formula

=AVERAGE(R:R,COUNTIFS(R:R,1,Q:Q,"Certified")/100)

When undoing some off the 100's in column R the dial would not change the percentage and when adding 100% it doesn't change the value either.

I use column Q for determining what value is it such as certified, showcase and advance.

Please let me know how I can modify the formula.

I tried removing the average R:R but the value is still incorrect.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean `=AVERAGE(R:R,COUNTIFS(R:R,1,Q:Q,"Certified"))/100` ?

Comment: No, I tried it out and it gives me the wrong value still.

Comment: Can you share some sample data and expected outcome with that sample?

Comment: 100%
100%
100%
100%
100%
100%
100%
100%
100%
100%
0%
100%
100%
100%
0%  This should total 87% but the dial is staying at 42% even when I change the 0's to 100's

Comment: Please post your data (both column R & Q) like this inside your question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9vBA.jpg

Comment: Also check how your data is formatted.